# Ektron to load JavaScript at the end of a page

Tags: javascript, ektron

Is there any way to get Ektron to load JavaScript at the end of a page as opposed to the <head> using

```
JS.RegisterJSInclude(this, _api.SitePath + "/js/last.js", "LastJS");
```

I'd like to get the benefits of using RegisterJSInclude, but the file needs to come in at the end of the html.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
...
<script src="/WorkArea/FrameworkUI/js/ektron.javascript.ashx?id=+1843595138+1354911990" type="text/javascript">
</body>
</html>
```

I am open to any alternatives as well.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible but you could make a template that has an asp content placeholder at the bottom and then use the asp control to add it. If you normally use the registerJS function then calling the script anywhere in the aspx page will technically make it seen last by the browser. Lastly you might want to look into using http://headjs.com/